# In Project Hail Mary, how did Eridians make sensors for electromagnetic radiation without understanding radiation?

Tags: project-hail-mary

In Andy Weir's Project Hail Mary, on page 224, we get the following conversation between Rocky and Grace:

> I try another approach. "Space has very very very fast hydrogen atoms. They move almost the speed of light. They were created by stars long long long ago."
>
> "*No. No mass in space. Space is empty.*"
>
> Oh boy. "No, that's wrong. There are hydrogen atoms in space. Very very fast hydrogen atoms."
>
> "*Understand.*"
>
> "You didn't know that?"
>
> "*No.*"
>
> I stare in shock.
>
> How can a civilization develop space travel without ever discovering radiation?

Later on, on page 236, Grace discovers why:

> All told, Erid's magnetic field is at least twenty-five times as strong as Earth's.
>
> Plus, their atmosphere is extremely thick. Twenty-nine times as thick.
>
> You know what strong magnetic fields and thick atmospheres are really good at? Radiation protection.

But much later on, we get the following on page 286:

> "*This device hear light. Like human eye.*"
>
> "Oh. It's a camera."
>
> ...
>
> "*What are wavelengths of light humans can see, question?*"
>
> "All wavelengths between 380 nanometers and 740 nanometers."
>
> ...
>
> "*Understand,*" he says. He turns a few knobs on his device. "*Now I 'see' what you can see.*"
>
> "You're an amazing engineer."
>
> He waves a claw dismissively. "*No. Camera is old technology. Display is old technology. Both were on my ship for science. I only modify to use inside.*"

which seems to indicate that the Eridians had technology for translating electromagnetic radiation into a texture that they can sense? But supposedly their planet had no way of receiving such radiation, period? Is this a contradiction?

Comment: I don't know anything about this series but from a real world perspective a blind species I suspect would figure out infrared radiation from heat and work the rest of photon physics out later.

Comment: @lucasbachmann: It's not a series, it's a novel.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you're over-generalizing "radiation" here. Though, the book, despite its hard science approach, is a bit guity of that too there. What the vernacular, and Grace at this point too, often means when they say "radiation" is usually [ionizing radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionizing_radiation). And specifically what the Eridians, due to their planet's condition, didn't know about was [cosmic radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray) (as well as [its effects on organisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_threat_from_cosmic_rays)).

However, **they very much know what electromagnetic radiation** is in general and how it works. Rocky knows what "light" is and also what wavelengths are and in fact the Eridians need to have sensors for it to actually "see" in space, since their own sound-based sensing doesn't work there. (Apart from many other physical processes that you need the concept of electromagnetic radiation for to understand.) That is even mentioned in the book by Grace at some point, as he also wonders why the Eridians could even see his ship, but then realizes they simply have their own sensors on their ship, in the same way Grace has sensors for electromagnetic radiation that he can't see either, like infrared.

Actually, the kind of cosmic radiation that Grace explains there isn't really [*electromagnetic* radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) (like light, microwaves or radio), rather than [*particle* radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_radiation). So, **Rocky knows what radiation is, he just doesn't know there's some kind of radiation in space and you got to be wary of it.**

You could say the Eridians are basically stuck at the beginning of the 20th century, without knowledge of relativistic physics and probably neither quantum processes. I think it's mentioned at some point that they never had much of a motivation to explore the broader space and we can also assume they likely aren't harnessing the power of nuclear fission or they'd know that fast core particles aren't good for you.